# NSObject variable with custom options/values

Tags: objective-c, xcode, variables, nsobject

I don't know if it's possible to declare a variable in objective c with some predefined values.

For example I want my object **"Location"** to have a variable called **type** whose possible values are: **"street"**, **"city"** or **"country"**.

The idea is to access it with something like:

```
Location *myLoction = [[Location alloc] init]
myLocation.type = city;
```

and later do something like:

```
if(myLocation.type == street) {
    //Do something here
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not really confortable with Strings... I don't feel safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for enums:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, LocationType) {
    LocationTypeStreet,
    LocationTypeCity,
    LocationTypeCountry
};

@interface Location : NSObject 

@property (nonatomic) LocationType type;

@end
```

You have to prefix the values, because you don't have namespaces.

```
if(myLocation.type == LocationTypeStreet) {
}
```

Comment: +1 `NS_ENUM` - did you by any chance read about `NS_ENUM` in [NSHipster]:(http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/) this week?

Comment: Actually I did, but I knew this before, since it was mentioned in the [Modern Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=405) video from WWDC 2012.

Comment: Awesome I've seen that video before but that was a long time ago - good to have the link to hand though

Comment: You can always look it up in a Cocoa header file, like UIView.h.